# CardDAV synchronization add-on for Thunderbird 31.x

Tags: thunderbird, carddav

Is there an add-on for Thunderbird 31.x which allows to "work" with its addresses in Thunderbird 31.x (send mails to, create lists, etc.). The CalDAV addressbook is provided by Horde groupware 5.1, but that shouldn't matter.

My research result (of contact synchronization add-ons) is so far:

- Addressbooks Synchronizer 1.1.2: "Not a real synchronization tool, just exchanges the files!"
- tzpush 1.8.9: doesn't seem to do anything (contacts are not available in horde after issueing "upload", but no error messsage is displayed
  SyncKolab 3.1.4: compatible with horde, but only for IMAP synchronization (not sure what this is supposed to mean regarding contacts)
- Google Task Sync 0.5.1: uses google API
- ThunderSync 2.1: synchronization only with filesystem
- Zindus 0.8.42: no longer supported[www.zindus.com/blog/2013/07/10/zindus-end-of-life/]
- gContactSync 1.0.0: setup wizard says that mail account needs to be a google account
- Inverse SOGo connector 24.0.6: installation only adds a tab in settings panel where contact categories can be added

Comment: With SOGo, you need to add remote address book (tools->address book; file->create->remote address book) and point it to your carddav srerver.

Answer (score 1):

tzpush does work with horde. You have to select the address book to sync in horde/Preferences for Address Book/Synchronization Preferences.

Any problems, feel free to contact developer (me): https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/tzpush

Answer (score -1):

The [Cardbook addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming) completely replaces Thunderbird's built-in address book and provides support for CardDAV, including synchronisation.

*Nota bene:* If you use HTTPS with a server that does not have a valid certificate (in particular a self-signed one) you need to add an exception for that server in Thunderbird's certificate configuration dialogue first.

Comment: How does sync work? Please show with some screenshots thanks!

Comment: Then post a screenshot of the UI, including the button. The question is about sync, and your answer does not talk about sync at all.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I do not see the value of posting a screenshot of a button. Support for CardDAV pretty much implies syncing, but there you go.